# How can I control HikariCP exceptions?

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception, jpa, hikaricp

I want—when (for some reason) the database has a problem and cannot make the connection with HikariCP—the service to start normally and is not terminated because the database is failing.

I tried to control the connection with try catch, also with `InitializationFailTimeout` and with `spring.datasource.continue-on-error: true`, but still the service does not start, maybe you have any other idea that I can try to use?

```
@Bean
public DBSecret dbSecret(Environment env) {
    return DBSecret.builder()
            .url(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.url"))
            .username(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.username"))
            .password(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.password"))
            .build();
}

@Bean
public DataSource datasource(DBSecret secret,
                             @Value("${spring.datasource.driverClassName}") String driverClass) {
    HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
    config.setJdbcUrl(secret.getUrl());
    config.setUsername(secret.getUsername());
    config.setPassword(secret.getPassword());
    config.setDriverClassName(driverClass);
    config.setConnectionTimeout(1800000);
    try {
        return connection(config);
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

private HikariDataSource connection(HikariConfig config){
    return new HikariDataSource(config);
}
```